# Jquery ui error

Tags: jquery

I could normally run webpages containing jquery ui elements. But, of late, firebug seems to

report an error **a.success.call.is not a function** and shows a *datepicker* tag as

erroneous..

Where could be the error? I even replaced the .js file... the error was initially in js but

now in my homepage...

Comment: disable datepicker and all its dependents, then debug.. If everything is fine now, you might have jquery version conflict

Comment: post the jquery and jquery ui versions and anyother javascript libraries you might be using...

Comment: <link type="text/css" href="css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
 <link type="text/css" href="tradingTipsCss.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
 <link type="text/css" href="listmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, a *tag*, ie an *element* is not a *function*, therefore it cannot be *called*. you passed a wrong argument as a success callback.

best help I could provide with the few you showed.